# AngularJS orderBy using objects

Tags: angularjs

I want to sort my products using these fields.

```
<select name="cars" class="form-control" ng-model="sortBy">
   <option value="volvo">Max: price</option>
   <option value="saab">Min: price</option>
   <option value="fiat">Date: Newest</option>
   <option>Mileage: Highest</option>
   <option>Mileage: Lowest</option>
   <option value="audi">Year: Oldest</option>
   <option value="audi">Year: Newest</option>
</select>
```

I displayed my data like this. But i didn't have an idea about how to sort these using above fields.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="border: none;box-shadow: 1px 1px 9px 1px #ccc;" ng-repeat="item in getitems_bybrand">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img ng-repeat="image in item.images | limitTo:1 | orderBy:sortBy" src="http://10.90.90.55/cars_app/backend/public/uploads/@{{image.name}}" class="img-thumbnail" width="400px" height="400px">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3><b>@{{ item.cars.year }} @{{ item.cars.name }}</b></h3>
        <h5 class="badge">&#8377; @{{ item.cars.price }},000</h5>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h5><strong>Mileage :</strong> <span>@{{ item.cars.milage }}</span></h5>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h5><strong>Specifications :</strong></h5>
            <p id="attributes">@{{ item.cars.specifications }}</p>  
          </div>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you give me you getitems_bybrand . ?

Comment: `Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 15 more… ]`

Comment: In the array each object contains an object and an array